# AppCenter not displaying showcased apps

Tags: release-loki, appcenter, apps

My AppCenter does not contain any of the apps in the [screenshot displayed on the elementaryOS website](https://elementary.io/#appcenter). For example, searching for NaSC as demoed comes up with nothing. I have tried installing from source, but nothing changes.

[image]

What should I do to get these apps in the AppCenter?
I am running 0.4.1 Loki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I found that my system was using the `elementary-os/daily` repository.
Removing this, replacing it with `ppa:elementary-os/stable`, and reinstalling AppCenter fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Last Sunday I installed elementary OS on my wife's laptop and I noticed that too. But in my case, I just needed to wait 2 minutes and after that every time I opened AppCenter it showed me all their apps. I think it was downloading some information to show, first.

Comment: I'd suggest either making sure about this, and make it a definitive answer ("I think it was" --> "it was"), or converting it to a comment.

Comment: I don't have reputation enough to do a comment in another answer. So, I was just trying to help with what happened for me.

Comment: That's a really annoying limitation of the StackExchange platform IMO. I'll flag your answer so that hopefully the moderators can turn it into a comment.